# sending the navigation params as props to other component

Tags: react-native, sendbird

I am using RN v0.46.4 , react-navigation and sendbird.

I am developing a chat application.

What I am trying to do is that navigating the user to Msg screen with two params `item` (contain user info) and `createdChannel` .

They are passed but only once i.e. each time I navigate to `Msg` screen for different users , I receive the same value on which I have presses first.

**Chat Screen**

```
_chat(item){

 // console.log(item);
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation

  var userIds = [item.id,1];
  sb = new SendBird({appId: APP_ID});
  sb.connect(1, function(user, error) {
         //console.log(user);
      sb.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds(userIds, true, item.firstname, function(createdChannel, error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }

   //console.log(createdChannel);
   navigate('Msg', { item, createdChannel })

});
```

Also, when I console `createdChannel` in `_chat function` , it gives the roght information as expected.

But when I console it in `Msg` screen , I receive only the first createdChannel created, already told above.

**Msg Screen**

```
 super(props);
  console.log(props.navigation.state.routes[1].params.createdChannel);
```

**My router structure:**

```
const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {

    Chat: {
      screen: ChatStack, 
      path: ""
    }
}
```

**ChatStack**

```
const ChatStack= StackNavigator({
      Chat:{screen: Chats,
      navigationOptions: {
       header: null,
     }},

      Msg: {
      screen: Msg,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation}) => ({
       title: `${navigation.state.params.item.firstname} ${navigation.state.params.item.lastname}`,
        tabBarVisible: false

      })
    },
    })
```

Comment: Which version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @animaonline, can you provide a minimal git repo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your Msg screen's constructor function, try accessing the `item` and `createdChannel` by calling `props.navigation.state.params.createdChannel`.

```
super(props);
console.log(props.navigation.state.params.createdChannel);
console.log(props.navigation.state.params.item);
```

Comment: @YaShChaudhary I think you might be running into one of the issues in here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/143, https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/80, checkout your router setup and see if those helps.

Comment: tysm for pointing to this issue, yes its the same issue I am facing but none of the solutions worked for me :(

Comment: @YaShChaudhary, in this case, you might want to change your question's description to let people have a better understanding on how you setup your router, and what each page looks like, then we can try to reproduce the structure locally and help you out.

Comment: So you have tried this:  `navigate("Msg",{},
  {
    type: "Navigate",
    routeName: "Msg",
    params: { item, createdChannel }
  }
)`,  and it doesn't work?

Comment: yes, I but with ChatStack `navigate("ChatStack', {}, {  type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
                                          routeName: "Msg",
                                            params: {item, createdChannel} 

                                          })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149935/discussion-between-dotcomxy-and-yash-chaudhary).

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in a similar situation. In my case the problem was because passing params to nested screen was intentionally removed from the lib (1.0.0-beta21 to 1.0.0-beta22).

**Note: But as of now, react-navigation version is v1.5.2**

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3252

Anyway, my quick and dirty solution is to use `screenProps` to inject props into screen.

```js
const ChatStack= StackNavigator({
  Chat:{ screen: Chats, ... },
  Msg: { screen: Msg, ... },
});

// Instead of exporting ChatStack directly, create a wrapper and pass navigation.state.params to screenProps

export default (props) => {
  const params = props.navigation.state.params;
  // const params = _.get(props, 'navigation.state.params');
  return (
    <ChatStack screenProps={params} />
  );
};
```

Now all screens under ChatStack can access those props injected.